# SOLR - adding custom REST service

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solr8

I am using SOLR 8.x. and I am trying to adding some custom functionality. Say like, triggering some server specific shell scripts. Adding custom code JARs to the lib folder and adding the jars in *solrconfig.xml* is not working.

Or how to set up new SOLR version in eclipse(most of the docs online are for older version where SOLR was still a .war)

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: How is it not working? Does the solr log show that your jar file gets loaded when starting up? Are you running in standalone or in cloud mode?

Comment: I am running it in cloud mode with external ZK and I don't see any info about the jar loaded in logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by adding the custom jar(HTTPServlet based) to server/lib folder and by updating web.xml with servlet & servlet-mapping.